# Error upon restoring variable

Tags: tensorflow, loading

I stumbled across an error that I am unable to resolve. What I am trying to do is the following thing:

I want to train a (dummy) model that adds `a` to `b` on every iteration. When finished, I want to save the variables as checkpoint. The first time I run it, it shall build the model from scratch. Every time I re-run the model, it should start from the last checkpoint and do the additions again. Hereby, I load the complete graph from the .meta file. The global step variable is there to keep track of the total number of steps I have trained.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file

# List ALL tensors.
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'), all_tensors=True, tensor_name='')

tf.reset_default_graph()

global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', shape=[], dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)

def model(a, b):
    b = tf.assign_add(b, a)
    return b

with tf.Session() as sess:

    ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./')
    if ckpt:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./my_test_model-1.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt)

    else:
        a = tf.Variable(3.0, name='a')
        b = tf.Variable(5.0, name='b')

        b = model(a, b)

        ### before EDIT
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        ###

        ### after EDIT
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        ###

    for step in range(5):
        global_step.assign_add(1).eval()
        print(global_step.eval())
        print(b.eval())

        saver.save(sess, './my_test_model', global_step=global_step)
```

The script runs fine for the first time, outputting this:

```
1        # step
8.0      # value of b
2
11.0
3
14.0
4
17.0
5
20.0
```

The second time I run the program, I get this output followed by an error:

```
tensor_name:  a
3.0
tensor_name:  b
20.0
tensor_name:  global_step
0
tensor_name:  global_step_1
5

INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./my_test_model-5
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): ... FailedPreconditionError:
>   Attempting to use uninitialized value global_step      [[Node:
>   AssignAdd_2 = AssignAdd[T=DT_INT32, use_locking=false,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](global_step, AssignAdd_2/value)]] ...

The first time, it's clear that it won't throw an error as I run the initializer for all variables. But I thought that restoring a model counts as some sort of initialization? I really cannot wrap my head around this concept. I also tried defining `global_step` after defining `a` and `b`, but this resulted in another error when loading for the first time:

> ValueError: Cannot use the default session to evaluate tensor: the
>   tensor's graph is different from the session's graph. Pass an explicit
>   session to `eval(session=sess)`.
>   The error refers to the the line that increments `global_step` (`global_step.assign_add(1).eval()`).

What am I doing wrong? Where should I define the variable?

I appreciate any help on this problem! Thank you for reading this far.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @Diana, the precondition error vanished. Unfortunately, another error occured. Whenever running the script with loading a checkpoint, it throws a name error:

> NameError: name 'global_step' is not defined.

This also happens for variable ´b´. Shouldn't be the name loaded when restoring the checkpoint? The tensors seem to have the right names and values when I check the tensors in the checkpoint file.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the saver after you ran initialize. Otherwise you don't save any value to it. As the saver does not know it.

Comment: Thank you for your input, the precondition error disappeared, but now another error occured. I edited it in my question.